# Plot 3d bodies given as surfaces (, given as vertices sequences)

Tags: plot, gnuplot

The title basically says it. I'd like to plot samples given in a form similar to the
cube below:

```
// Front
0 0 0
0 0 1
1 0 1
1 0 0

// Back
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 0

// Left
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 0 1

// Right
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 0 1

// Bottom
0 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
0 1 0

// Top
0 0 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
```

I'm not constrained to any particular program, but I assume gnuplot can be used to do it. How would you do it? (Of course I've tried to find it out myself, but I'm a gnuplot noob and gnuplot is too big to find answers directly)

Answer (score 0):

I had to rearrange your datafile a little bit:

```
#front
0 0 0
0 0 1

1 0 0
1 0 1


#back
0 1 0
0 1 1

1 1 0
1 1 1


#left
0 0 0
0 1 0

0 0 1
0 1 1


#right
1 0 0
1 1 0

1 0 1
1 1 1


#bottom
0 0 0
1 0 0

0 1 0
1 1 0


#top
0 0 1
1 0 1

0 1 1
1 1 1
```

this can then be plotted with:

```
set pm3d depthorder
splot "datafile.dat" u 1:2:3:-2 w pm3d
```

While this works (mostly -- sorting by depthorder isn't perfect in gnuplot), it would quickly become tedious to do more complicated shapes.

Basically, it works because I specify each quadrilateral (square in this case) separately in the datafile -- quadrilaterals are separated by 2 blank lines.  Each square is composed of the 4 vertices sorted in 2 "scans.  So, the first scan you go from point (0,0,0) to (0,0,1).  Then the next scan goes from (1,0,0) to (1,0,1).  Gnuplot then connects the scans together.

Using this technique, you can also make triangles (triangles are just quadrilaterals where the last two points are the same ;).

Finally, the coloring of each surface is done by the `pseudo-column` "-2" -- which is really just the quadrilateral number.  You could add a fourth field in the datafile and use that for the color if you prefer.

However, I have a feeling that this solution using gnuplot isn't really what you're looking for since this sort of thing isn't really what gnuplot was designed for -- There's probably a tool out there which would do this much more easily -- I just don't know what it is.